# Jest + Typescript lint error: TS2339: Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

My Jest tests are running on react native but when I check Typescript linter I get this error:

`error TS2339: Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ childr...'.`

I'm working on react-native by the way.

This the jest line throwing the error:
`const home = shallow(<Home store={store}/>)`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your `Home` is wrapped component returned by `connect()`.
In that case, there are several options to handle this in tests:

1) If you don't need connected props and action for testing then just use not wrapped `Home` component as described here https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#connected-components

2) Wrap your component with `Provider`, eg; `wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Home /></Provider>`. The downside is that your snapshots will contain information about Provider too, you can't test just `Home` component using shallow.

3) Extend `IntrinsicAttributes` in some `.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicAttributes {
    store: any;
  }
}
```

and include it for tests.

Comment: no, the point of shallow is NOT to use mount so I reject this answer.  Using mount renders the entire tree and there is a reason people want to use shallow so changing your test to use mount isn't a change without side effects, you're suggesting a change in HOW they're actually testing completely

Comment: how do I include it for tests?  where? how?